# View numpy array as image while debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: image, numpy, debugging, pycharm

Is it possible to view numpy array as image while debugging in PyCharm?

I tried to enter

```
PIL.Image.fromarray(my_data, 'RGB').show()
```

into watches, but got

> PIL is not defined

error. This is probably because PIL was not imported in current module.

Any other way appreciated. May be can write my own viewer or something?

Comment: Why not just install PIL?

Answer (score 19):

I've just created OpenCV Image Viewer Plugin, which displays image while debugging just on click. You can install it to any JetBrains IDE, which support Python (directly or via plugin).

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Comment: god bless u dude

Comment: It's seems cannot use to PIL.Image? Or there is the same tool to PIL.Image?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't support PIL Images for now.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to import packages with semicolon, and was able to show image with expression like below:

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(mydata)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'